# Transform device orientation to world frame in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'd like to transform the yaw, pitch and roll of the iPhone from the body frame to the world frame, i.e. azimuth, pitch and roll. On Android this is easily done with the 
SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(), SensorManager.getOrientation methods as detailed here: http://blog.mysticlakesoftware.com/2009/07/sensor-accelerometer-magnetics.html

Are similar methods available for the iPhone or can someone point me in the right direction how to do this transformation?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The accelerometer is good enough to get gravity direction vector in device coordinate system. That is in case when device calms down.

The next step for full device orientation is to use `CLLocationManager` and get the true north vector in device coordinate system. 
With the normalized true north vector and gravity vector you can easily get all other directions using the dot and cross vectors product.

Answer (score 0):

The accelerometer (`UIAccelerometer`) will give you a vector from the device's accelerometer chip straight down.  If you can assume that the device is being held fairly steady (*i.e.*, that you're not reading acceleration from actual movement), then you can use simple trig (acos(), asin()) to determine the device's orientation.

If you're worried that the device might be moving, you can wait for several accelerometer readings in a row that are nearly the same.  You can also filter out any vector with a length that's ± TOLERANCE (as you define it) from 1.0

In more general terms, the device has no way of knowing its orientation, other than by "feeling gravity", which is done via the accelerometer.  The challenges you'll have center around the fact that the accelerometer feels all acceleration, of which gravity is only one possible source.

Answer (score 0):

If you're targeting a device with a gyroscope (iPhone 4 at the time of writing), the CoreMotion framework's `CMMotionManager` can supply you with `CMDeviceMotion` updates.  The framework does a good job of processing the raw sensor data and separating `gravity` and `userAcceleration` for you.  You're interested in the gravity vector, which can define the pitch and roll with a little trig.  To add yaw, (device rotation around the gravity vector) you'll also need to use the CoreLocation framework's CLLocationManager to get compass heading updates.